# Is there a way to make the forge categories remembered?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I open the forge dialog, I can see various item categories, and I can click the "fold" button (highlighted below) to hide and un-hide them:

[image: fold button screenshot]

This is incredibly useful, since that list does tend to get long and when I play a Demon Hunter I don't care about melee weapnos, when I play a Monk I don't care about quivers and mighty weapons, etc. etc.

Unfortunately this menu does not seem to remember which category was open and which was closed between game sessions, so every time I open it in a game it resets all categories to be open.

Is there a way to make it "stick", so it will remember which category was what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to make it remember collapsed category, unfortunately. The first thing I usually do when I open a craft tab is select the `Can Equip` option from `Show` combobox (also this is not remembered). Hopefully it will be fix in a future patch.

Comment: I've found the 'Can Equip' setting *does* get retained.